# JavaScript type: "GET" not getting to controller from jQuery dataTable

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, controller, datatables

This is weird (to me)!  I can get to the controller by making a straight up ajax call but when I try to make the very same call from inside the dataTable code block, execution never gets in the controller.

I'm new with jQuery datatables but I have other instances in the code base to use as examples.  I cannot figure out what is wrong here.

## This code gets into the controller:

```
getAssets = function () {
    // converting array of int(s) to a string
    var ids = selectedIds.toString();
    // setting the data for controller parameters
    var oData = { "facIds": ids, "type": selectedType };

    $.ajax({
        url: "api/services/getassetsbyids",   //  This call gets into the controller
        type: "GET",
        data: oData,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            var look = result;
        }   
    });
}
```

## This code does NOT get into the controller:

```
initSelectableAssetTable = function () {

    jQueryVar.jSelectableAssetTable.dataTable({
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bAutoWidth": true,
        "aoColumns": [
            { "mDataProp": "AssetId", "bSortable": true },
            { "mDataProp": "AssetName", "bSortable": true }
        ],
        "aoColumnDefs": [
        { "mDataProp": null, "sDefaultContent": " ", "aTargets": [-1] }
        ],
        "sDom": '<"top">rt<"bottom"><"clear">',
        "oLanguage": {
            "sEmptyTable": "No Assets found."
        },
        "sAjaxSource": $.baseURL("api/services/getassetsbyids"),
        "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
            var ids = selectedIds.toString();
            var oData = { "facIds": ids, "type": selectedType };
            $.ajax({
                url: sSource, //  This never gets into the controller
                type: "GET",
                data: oData,
                dataType: "json",
                success: fnCallback,
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, erroThrown) {
                    alert(jqXHR.responseText);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

**I've even tried replacing sSource with the URL to no avail.**  Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

## Controller Code:

```
[HttpGet]
public List<AssetDTO> getassetsbyids(string facIds, string type)
{
    List<AssetDTO> assets = new List<AssetDTO>();
    List<int> ids = Array.ConvertAll<string, int>(facIds.Split(','), new Converter<string, int>(Convert.ToInt32)).ToList();
    IAssetService service = new AssetService();
    if(type.Equals("rack"))
    {
        assets = service.getrackassetsbyids(ids);
    } else {
        assets = service.getassetsbyids(ids);
    }
    return assets;
}
```

Comment: Have you check the ajax callback error from your second snippets?

Comment: The cursor jumps over the entire method and never gets into the error block.  I'll post an update.

Comment: Any chance the fnServerData function is not triggered at all?

Comment: I'll be looking into that.  Thanks for the pointer!  :-)

Comment: You're missing `"bServerSide": true,` from the datatables initialisation code.

Comment: @markpsmith - YOU"RE A GENIUS!  That was it.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't directly address your issue, but try using the first snippet that works and then defining/initializing your datatable in the success function.

For instance, in my `success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {`,
I always assign the data parameter to the data property of the datatable.

Comment: Expand your answer to show me how I would do that and I'll upvote your suggestion.